# Search result not showing task for logged in user / for administrator does

Tags: search, search-results

I am new to search engine. However, I do not get the following behavior from sharepoint.

I added OOTB Core search results web part to a page, defined fixed query to `contentclass:STS_ListItem_Tasks`. I created task under user and also assigned it to him. Run full crawl. I see nothing in results. If I login under administrator I can see the task. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

edited:
The search is not working for users belongs to other domain than the search service application account belongs to. Probably [this thread deal](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/sharepoint2010general/thread/e991b9e9-1f21-4024-ac56-dfd223d347ed) with it, during work week check with it department and let you know.

Comment: Search results are security trimmed, it seems that your user doesn't have sufficient permissions on search result. Double check that user can access (at least view) on created task in sharepoint

Comment: hi, thanks for suggestion. however I double checked it. User is able to create task in the list, edit the task and also remove it. I also done index reset. Retasksult is the same. Its really strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a Task to a user doesn't mean that search results will show the task to the user. User needs to have at least Read permissions on that particular Site Collection/Sub-Site and/or List to be able to see the task because Search performs Security Triming.

Also very important is the account you are using to perform the Search, also known as "Default Content Access Account" - it must be having Read for the COntent Database. The blog you are mentioning points to an issue related to  pre-Windows 2008 - is this your case?